# JSON date, display original date in the server's timezone

Tags: javascript, json, date, momentjs

For example, I have a string date like this (I'm getting this from the server in json, from rails app)

```
s = "2013-09-01T00:00:00.000+08:00"
```

I would like to display it like so

```
01.09.2013
```

So I'm using moment.js library for this

```
moment(s).zone("+08:00").format("DD.MM.YYYY")
>> "01.09.2013"
```

But I don't know if needed timezone is +08:00. If I skip `.zone()` call, result would be wrong because my browser is in differnt timezone

```
moment(s).format("DD.MM.YYYY")
>"31.08.2013"
```

Even though in my original string I had `+08:00` at the end.

So, my question is how can I extract time zone from json date string using pure javascript or moment.js library?

The simplest way I can think of is extracting the last 6 characters manually,

```
s.slice(s.length - 6, s.length)
> "+08:00"
```

But maybe there is a better approach for this task?

Comment: Do you control rails code ? there's a `#utc` method on Time in ruby (and on DateTime in ruby on rails) which translates time to utc. This would be a good way to avoid timezone headaches. Also, please note that rails timezone format is not necessary numbers, but can also be things like "CEST".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `parseZone` function, like so:

```
moment.parseZone(s)
```

[Documentation is here.](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/)

Alternatively, you can use the older approach, which does the same thing:

```
moment(s).zone(s)
```

Comment: Note, in order for that to work, you need to be passing a time zone *offset* like you showed in your question.  If you are passing a name or abbreviation like Olivier mentioned in the question comments, it will not work.