# Display datetime with MomentJs without timezone conversion

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Sometimes I end up with a datetime on the front end of a web site that has already been adjusted to a specific time zone, and I wish to display it exactly as is regardless of the user's timezone.

For example let's say I have this date:

> 2015-01-22T16:11:36.36-07:00

The -07:00 means it is in Mountain Time, and MomentJs knows this and will automatically adjust for users in other timezones.  For example say I display the datetime with this code:

```
moment('2015-01-22T16:11:36.36-07:00').format('l LT')
```

A user in Central time (-06:00) will see the time as 5:11PM instead of 4:11PM.  How can I tell MomentJs to not adjust for the user's timezone and display the datetime as is?

Comment: After reading your post following my answer below, it sounds like you may actually want to display the time as 4:11 PM for all users regardless of their timezone. If that is the case the `utc()` approach will not work. Additionally, if that is what you want to do, is the timezone of the time represented in some other way to the end user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON date, display original date in the server's timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002255/json-date-display-original-date-in-the-servers-timezone)

Comment: It's similar but the title of that question is misleading for this use case.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use the `utc()` method of moment to remove the timezone and display everything in universal time.

```
moment.utc('2015-01-22T16:11:36.36-07:00').format('l LT')
```

That will display the time as it is in UTC without any timezone offset. If you  want to display the time as it was recorded in the user/server timezone you can parse the zone information when you construct a moment instance and have it use the timezone recorded in the parsed string.

```
moment.parseZone('2015-01-22T16:11:36.36-07:00').format('l LT');
```

With either of these approaches you should consider labeling the time in some way to reflect the timezone the time corresponds to. Failing to do this could lead to a lot of confusion for the end users.

Comment: This works, however I was looking for a simpler solution to avoid doing it this way.  As it stands I'd have to put this logic inside of handlebars templates which would be really nasty.  Maybe the right solution is to change how the data is returned from the server, but I'll be looking at other client side solutions as well.

Comment: If you do end up putting it on the client side, I'd recommend doing so as a handlebars helper so that the logic is only done once and you can easily include it in your templates with a simple markup tag.

Comment: As an aside, how are these times being displayed to the end user? It seems odd that a requirement would like to have times represented in their original timezones without converting the time on the client.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on that when I can research it more and determine where the problem really is.

Comment: This actually doesn't work.  `offsetInMinutes` will be of the local time zone where the code is running, which won't necessarily be the offset that was passed in.  The correct solution is to use `moment.parseZone`, as shown in the dup link.

Comment: I see you edited, but note that the rest of the code is no longer needed.  `parseZone` does all the work.  Also, it's never a good idea (in general) to adjust a timestamp to an offset by adding or subtracting.  That actually shifts the moment to a *different* moment in time.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Johnson for the correction. The answer has been edited to use `moment.parseZone()`

Answer (score 42):

You can use the [utcOffset](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) method to set the offset manually.

```
moment().utcOffset(0, true).format()
```

Comment: This is really helpful as I wanted to treat the time from user as UTC (its a date) without converting it

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I tested with ```.utcOffset(0, true)``` still calculates the timezone. But when I used ```.utcOffset(0, false)``` it fixed.

Comment: this doesnt work, with true or false.  Getting hours and minutes from `2022-10-27T19:15:00.000-04:00` results as `02:15` for my timezone

Answer (score 2):

I created an extension to display the datetime without trying to adjust to the user's timezone:

```
(function (moment) {
    moment.fn.nozone = function () {
        var m1 = moment(this);
        var offsetInMinutes = m1.utcOffset();
        return m1.utc().add(offsetInMinutes, 'm');
    };
}(moment));
```

This way it is easily reusable, even in javascript templates.