# Changed time zone in request

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I'm sending moment object in request, but unfortunately the date is changing. For example when I choosed some date and I write to console, the date is ok, but in the request time is few hour early what is change the date.

console: Fri Oct 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 - ok,
In sent json: "2021-09-30T22:00:00.000Z" - wrong

Why it happens and how to fix it.

Comment: The second string is actually the same as the first one but is a UTC time (notice the 'Z' at the end). If you convert that back to a date again - it should give you the first result.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41337407/1858357) will help.

Comment: In console check moment().toJSON() this is passing in sent json which is UTC value of what you see in moment object