# Moment js - format datetime string without considering time zone value

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Consider that the string is `'2022-02-27T16:45:00-0500'`

I need to display it as **February 27, 2022, 04:45pm**

I tried the following code

```
moment(dateString).format('MMMM D, YYYY, hh:mma')
```

But it is returning the value as `'February 28, 2022, 03:15am'`. Any idea on how to fix this?

Edit:

I have the following code

```
moment(dateString).utcOffset(0, true).format('MMMM D, YYYY, hh:mma')
```

This returns the output as
**'February 28, 2022, 03:15am'**

Comment: what is it returning instead?

Comment: how do expect the output to be and what's the return / error you're getting?

Comment: [Display datetime with MomentJs without timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198626/display-datetime-with-momentjs-without-timezone-conversion)

Comment: @HyunjuneKim it does not work. I have modified the description with the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set `utcOffset` to -300 which is in minutes for -5 hrs
`moment().utcOffset(dateString)._offset` will give you the offset in minutes

```js
let dateString = '2022-02-27T16:45:00-0500'

let ans = moment(dateString).utcOffset(moment().utcOffset(dateString)._offset).format('MMMM D, YYYY, hh:mma')

console.log(ans)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```